# Allow hardware scanner input into a Flutter iOS App

Tags: ios, flutter, hardware, barcode-scanner

currently I am developing a Flutter iOS app. This Flutter app basically only contains a flutter_inappwebview fetching a certain URL.

All is fine, until I need to connect a hardware Datalogic QR scanner to the iOS device (in this case an iPad). The scanner starts up well, but when I scan a barcode/QR code the input from the scanner is not transferred to the Flutter app.

I've tried searching on internet, but no luck so far... Did anyone of you happen to get this working? Thanks in Advance!

P.S. I am fairly new to flutter, so it could also be my lack of experience here playing a role.

Comment: Assuming the scanner emulates a Bluetooth keyboard, do you have a text field with active focus to receive the scanned data?

Comment: Yes, but there is additional javascript to catch scanner input immediately that isn't working either. It looks like the 'keyboard' input is not forwarded into the Flutter app.

Comment: @LukeHouben Have you figured it out how to integrate with the scanner?